# How to deal with repeated small edits

Tags: discussion, edits

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941932/f-immutable-data-structures-for-high-frequency-real-time-streaming-data) has seem a whole stack of very small edits.  In particular the last 4 edits were all < 6 characters.

Is there some mechanism to discourage such repeated small edits aside from CW which doesn't kick in after a very long timeThe user has a history of doing this, see for example:?

It is possible that the author may just be doing repeated edits to ensure that the post is always near the top of the "active" list.

For another example by the same user see [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500660/t-sql-update-else-insert-stored-procedure-with-rank-partition-function-sql-20).

Comment: Simple. Flag them.

Comment: but the edits were made by the OP... And most of them are just a couple minutes apart...

Comment: If his posts become CW, then that's his problem, not ours.

Comment: There was another user doing the same for bumping his question/answers to the recents' list and gain rep. Can't find the exact thread on [MSO] now.

Comment: If he's made 10 edits in an effort to get more up-votes, it hasn't exactly worked (+3). And like @Cole said, if he ends up pushing it to Community Wiki, that *may* teach him something about the process and why he should cut that out. That said, I've often had cases where I tweak a post to get it perfect. I don't think I've ever gotten to revision 11 but I'm sure I've hit 5 or 6.

Comment: Not sure if I agree with the duplicate; I guess it depends on what folks think about someone editing *their own* posts incessantly vs. editing *other peoples'* posts.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I don't think he is looking for upvotes - just looking for an answer.

Comment: @John well, it hasn't worked for that either. :-) The only answer was posted very shortly after the question was created. I get your point though - the real motivation doesn't matter if the symptom is abuse.